# Upload file with progress bar

Tags: javascript, ajax

I create this code to upload file usin ajax and php and I want to add 
progress bar to show percent of upload.

this my code

```
<script>
   $("form#data").submit(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: "functions/video.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = data;
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
<form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="up_vid" type="file" id="up_vid"/>
<div class="upload_v_icon"></div>
<div class="video_info">
    <input type="text" name="video_title" placeholder="Video title" />
    <input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="funny,9gag,nice,crazy ..."/>
    <textarea name="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="bg_upload">
    <p>When you upload this video your are agree with <a href="">Terms</a> of service.</p>
    <button>Begin Upload</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think that `async: false,` is gonna be a problem. First, is it not AJAX, if it is not async, then it's nearly deprecated. I do not think you can use callback and async:false at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

This assumes a 1px wide gif called "progress.gif" is present. Set the color of this to the color you want your progress bar to appear.

Add something like this to your css:

```
.uploadBar {
   background-image:url(/images/progress.gif);
   background-position: -1px;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-size=0% 100%; width:100%;
   position: relative; overflow: hidden;
}
```

Add something like this to your $.ajax();

```
xhr: function() {
   var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
   //Upload progress
   xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
      var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
      console.log(percentComplete);
      $('.uploadBar').css({ backgroundSize: (percentComplete*100) + '%'});
      }
   }, false);
   return xhr;
   }
```

Comment: Wrap your jQuery in `$(document).ready(function() { });` or put the `<script></script>` below the form.